# UITableView Display Animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm using UITableView for showing banners which shows image and title.

https://youtu.be/4CnfZLWE3VI

The youtube link shows the animation of filtering banners. When I press "fav" button, it does not animate smoothly.
I'd like to have the animation smooth.

This is my swift code of `UITableView`.

```swift
extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredTournamentlist.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "entryCell", for: indexPath) as? TournamentEntryCell {

            cell.usernameLabel.text = filteredTournamentlist[indexPath.row].master_info.name
            cell.titleTabel.text = self.filteredTournamentlist[indexPath.row].name
            cell.dateLabel.text = DatetimeHelper.StringFromString(
                string: self.filteredTournamentlist[indexPath.row].eventDate,
                fromFormat: DatetimeHelper.DBDateFormat,
                toFormat: DatetimeHelper.JPStringFormat
            )
            cell.gameInfoLabel.text = self.filteredTournamentlist[indexPath.row].gameName
                
            self.tournamentModel.getThumbnail(path: self.filteredTournamentlist[indexPath.row].thumbnail_path) { image in
                cell.thumbnailView.image = image
            }
            self.profileInfoModel.getIcon(path: self.filteredTournamentlist[indexPath.row].master_info.icon_path) { icon in
                cell.iconView.image = icon
            }
                
            let selectedView = UIView()
            selectedView.backgroundColor = Colors.plain
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
            
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

It just sets some information around banner. And this↓ is a code of collectionview which shows filter buttons such as "fav" and "plan".

```swift
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "buttonCell", for: indexPath) as! PlainSquareButtonCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.button.setTitle(fileterButtonLabels[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        
        let input = HomeViewModel.Input(
            getHomeTournamentsTrigger: Driver.never(),
            getUserInfo: Driver.never(),
            filter: cell.button.rx.tap
                .map { [unowned self] in
                    return self.fileterButtonLabels[indexPath.row]
                }
                .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete(),
            down: cell.rx.downButton
                .map { b in
                    return b
                }.asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()
        )
        let output = homeViewModel.transform(input: input)

        output.filteredTournamentList
        .drive(onNext: { [unowned self] tournamentList in
            self.filteredTournamentlist = tournamentList
            self.cardTableView.reloadData()
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

The tableView shows every information in `filteredTournamentlist`, and the content of `filteredTournamentlist` is changed by the filter buttons.

I don't know how to make the animation smooth...
Help me!

Answer (score 2):

```
.drive(onNext: { [unowned self] tournamentList in
            self.filteredTournamentlist = tournamentList
            self.cardTableView.reloadData() // <<---------  RELOAD DATA
        })
```

Calling `reloadData()` will not give you the expected animation. What ever changes are going to happen when you tap on `fav` button you need to first determine and then you can apply those changes inside `beginUpdates()` & `endUpdates()` block.

It seems you have single section in the table view showing items, if so then it will be simpler for me to explain how to achieve the table view reload animation.

#### Step 1: Determine the changes

1. Calculate number of rows before and after tap on `fav` or `plan` button from your data source.
2. Determine the `IndexPath`s which are going to be changed (reload, add, delete).

#### Step 2: Apply changes on table view with animation

Apply the change inside `cardTableView.beginUpdates()` & `cardTableView.endUpdates()`.

Here is sample code for that

```
// ONLY CONSIDERING SINGLE SECTION, CALCULTION WILL BE COMPLEX FOR MULTI SECTION TABLEVIEW


// 1. Calculation of IndexPaths which are going to be impacted
let oldCellCount = dataSource.numberOfRowsInSection(0) // Get cell count before change
let newCellCount = dataSource.numberOfRowsInSection(0) // Get cell count after the change

var indexPathsToReload: [IndexPath] = []
var indexPathsToInsert: [IndexPath] = []
var indexPathsToDelete: [IndexPath] = []

if oldCellCount > newCellCount {
    // Need to delete and reload few cells
    indexPathsToReload = (0..<newCellCount).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
    indexPathsToDelete = (newCellCount..<oldCellCount).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
} else if oldCellCount < newCellCount {
    // Need to add and reload few cells
    indexPathsToReload = (0..<oldCellCount).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
    indexPathsToInsert = (oldCellCount..<newCellCount).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
} else {
    // No change in cell count
    indexPathsToReload = (0..<newCellCount).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}
}

// 2. Reload with animation
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsToDelete, with: .none) <<--- Use your expected animation here `fade`, `right`, `top`, `left` & more
tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathsToReload, with: .none)
tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToInsert, with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```